# make string initcap like if i enter paul james in textbox it should give me Paul James

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

make string initcap like if i enter paul james in textbox it should give me Paul James ..do it with javascript with and without inbuild functions.... make string initcap ?

brief:i dont want to use any inbuilt javaacript function like split and all...i just want to init cap that is "My Name Is In Init Cap"..i want my string in this format withour split and all

```
<input type="text" placeholder="enter string"/>
   <button>make string uppercase</button><!--like Paul James if i enter paul james-->
```

Comment: It is really annoying when websites decide they know better how to spell or capitalize your name, especially if your website is to be used internationally. For example in the Netherlands, certain last names have an 'infix' between first and last name, which should be lower case when both first and last name are present, and only capitalized if the first name is absent.

Answer (score 1):

Why use javascript, when you can use CSS?

```
button:focus{text-transform:capitalize;}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wgLao126/

Comment: coz i know css well i well i want to do it with javascript coz i want to learn it

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple :

```
    var a = MakeUpperCase("dean jones");
    function MakeUpperCase(str)
    {
        var strsplt = str.split(" ");
        var completestr ="";
        for(var i=0;i<strsplt.length;i++){
        var d =               strsplt[i].replace(strsplt[i].charAt(0),strsplt[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase());
    completestr += d + " ";
}
alert(completestr);
}
```

Comment: please mark answer if its correct for you

Comment: thanks it working ,i have one more question y u declare this completestr to blank thn in loop u used it..can u explain

Comment: I have used completestr to return string from function. I have taken for loop for passing any kind of string like dean jones larry so it will return string Dean Jones Larry. you can do anything it depends on your requirement.

Comment: what if i dont wana ujse any inbuild functions like spilt and all